# Items unpinned from taskbar are back after restart/sign out on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I have got a new installation of windows recently. Now when I do unpin items from taskbar that were there (IE, Edge, Explorer), they do come back after restart. A pinned chrome does not disappear though e.g.

Anything to fix this issue?

P.S. Just created a new user, and he has the same problem

P.P.S. Sign out is enough to get it back, no full restart needed

Comment: Does anyone know what causes this? Is it actually a Windows Update? If so can we band together and lynch the person who made this decision?

Comment: I think it's domain policies, at least in my case

Answer (score 257, accepted):

I had the same problem. Nothing works.

Finally, I found the XML file in my profile:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\LayoutModification.xml
```

The items were listed here in this section:

```
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection PinListPlacement="Replace">
    <defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
      <taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
-- items were here - removed
      </taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
    </defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
  </CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
```

Maybe this will help someone.

Comment: I have found items in there as well, will try to delete them and see if it works

Comment: I tried removing the items and even the file, but not work... Windows 10 Pro 10.0.16299

Comment: This worked for me on Win10 Enterprise v.1803, thanks!

Comment: That file doesn't exist on my hard drive, nor does a text search for `CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection` or `DefaultLayoutOverride` in my `AppData` folder yield any results... there is a `DefaultLayouts.xml` file in the location you specified, but it seems to contain data for the default start menu layout (which I don't use, since ClassicShell is so much better). Any other options where that setting might live (on Win 10 Pro)?

Comment: In my case I had to edit `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\LayoutModification.xml`

Comment: This worked, thanks! I commented out the entire `<CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>` section. To do this, type `<!--` right before the `<CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>` line, and then type `-->` after the `</CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>` line.

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise 1809 -- worked for me as well. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this works, but don't forget to also unpin the icons manually after editing the XML file.

Answer (score 17):

I managed to find a [solution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ea29e03-c917-4ce2-8c19-aae99d16fa74/prevent-edge-from-pinning-itself-to-the-taskbar-automatically-under-all-circumstances?forum=win10itprosetup) on Microsoft Technet.

I've also, personally found another way around it:

1. Open the explorer or the run prompt and go to `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell`
2. Edit the LayoutModification.xml file using the Notepad or some other text-only editor
3. Locate the `<taskbar:TaskbarPinList></taskbar:TaskbarPinList>` entry and in that entry remove the line `<taskbar:... />` adding Edge
4. Save that file and reboot.

This will not survive "major" updates to the system/Edge such as the
    April 2018 one, but you can simply do the above again to get rid of
    that impolite shortcut.

Comment: Hey James, welcome to Super User. Just an FYI, when linking to a solution on another site, it is preffered to restate the salient points of the linked solution in case the link becomes dead at a later date. Looking forward to seeing more from you in the future.

Answer (score 7):

First, go the following paths:

- `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`
- `C:\Users\Public\company name\TaskBar` (if this path doesn’t exist, ignore it)

Delete the items that you don’t want to show in taskbar.

Restart computer to see the result.

If no help, backup personal data, remove current account and create a new one, maybe your account is corrupted.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the items are not there after I unpin them. They come back after restart though (interestingly enough Edge shortcut is not there but still is pinned). New user got the same probelm

Comment: when those items come back, please try to delete them directly from explorer path rather than unpin.

Comment: There is a .bat file which could clear all pinned apps on taskbar, you could have a try.
How to Reset and Clear All Pinned Apps on Taskbar in Windows 10
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3151-reset-clear-taskbar-pinned-apps-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Deleting items directly did not help unfortunately and I'd prefer not to run bat files on init if possible

Comment: seems like your system is coming back to same state after restart regardless of what you do. could be a reason of malware or corrupted settings/registry

Comment: This began after the clean installation of Windows on my machine, so I doubt it's malware, but a good question is how to uncorrupt it? :)

Answer (score 7):

It appears that this was some corporate policy from domain that have done that and it's not possible to turn off that easy, but anyway, domain rules are a possibility when this happens.

Answer (score 4):

It's the default behavior.
I was searching far and wide for the solution to this issue, and then I realized something:
The file `LayoutModification.xml` was simply not there.

So rather than try to look elsewhere for those stubborn icons, you could just remove them by **creating** your own file:

1. Go to the path where the file is supposed to be: `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\`
2. Open a text editor of your choice and create an empty file with the name `LayoutModification.xml`.
3. Paste the following layout in([reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-10-taskbar#sample-taskbar-configuration-xml-file)):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LayoutModificationTemplate
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification"
    xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout"
    xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout"
    xmlns:taskbar="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/TaskbarLayout"
    Version="1">
  <CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection PinListPlacement="Replace">
    <defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
      <taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Notepad.lnk" />
      </taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
    </defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
 </CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

Notice the  `PinListPlacement="Replace"` on line 8. That'll remove the old icons you have(bye bye annoying Edge and Store icons!) and add any you specify in the list(like the Notepad one I have here). Note that this doesn't affect the icons that you explicitly pin to the taskbar(those are controlled by the `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` folder).

**Note**: If you find the need to add any more icons, don't trust names in Explorer! Go to the General tab of the shortcut(`.lnk` file) you want to add and copy the path from there. The Explorer tends to have different names for some folders - mine had a name of "Windows Accessories" for a folder and a path name of just "Accessories". If you put the wrong path in, your icon won't show.

Answer (score 2):

For my case, it doesn't work if I go to:

`C:\Users\\**yourusername**\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell`

Instead, I go to:

`C:\Users\\**Default**\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell`

There's LayoutModification.xml there. Everything is fixed after removing the Taskbar pin just like the top answer suggested:

```
 </DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection PinListPlacement="Replace">
    <defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
      <taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
-- items were here - removed
      </taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
    </defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
  </CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the similar solution to prevent Opera automatically pinning itself to the taskbar each run. The solution provided above didn't work for me as both LayoutModification.xml in "default" and my user folders didn't contain such sections. I found working the suggestion in the following article:

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-pinning-or-unpinning-of-taskbar-items-in-windows-10

I added the "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\NoPinningToTaskbar" DWORD32 option and set it to 1 then restarted Windows Explorer via the Task Manager and voila - after the next Opera start and exit it was not pinned anymore. But note that along with that "pin to taskbar" context option disappears as well from the context menu so if you need this option later again enable it back.